# dividing the records using div tags

Tags: apex, visualforce, html5

kindly let me know how to divide the below records using apex:repeat in 2 columns using div tags 
Visualforce:-

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!sa.Country_Languages__r}" var="cLang">
    <apex:outputtext value="{!cLang.Display_Name__c}" />
  </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using Css

```
<apex:repeat value="{!sa.Country_Languages__r}" var="cLang">
    <div id="div1"><apex:outputtext value="{!cLang.Display_Name__c}" /></div>
  </apex:repeat> 

<style>
#div1{
  height: 30px;
  width: 49%;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  background-color: #0066CC;
  float: left;
}

</style>
```

Then you will get UI like [image]

[JS Fiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/76Raj/1286/)

Comment: Thnx for your response. Really appreciate it.One more issue . Suppose 13 records are there , i want to display 10 on one side and 3 on the other side. Please help.

Comment: @vineet then you might need to use wrapper to display as you want.

Comment: thnx once again. actually wrapper at this stage i don't know how to implement it . any help would be highly apppreciated.